# Inappropriate Server response in upload failure error block net.gotev.uploadservice.ServerResponse@73e7f34

Tags: nativescript, angular-nativescript

I am facing issue in getting server response in error block (callback) of plugin  NativeScript/nativescript-background-http  in mobile app development for uploading file. On basis on error server response will perform other operation

Error Call back of plugin nativescript-background-http
Uploading the file to server , I have been able to read the response in responded callback but that is a case of success.

```
task.on("responded", (e:any)=>{
               //response 
                let response= JSON.parse(e.data)
          });
```

in case of error it is not working

```
 let task = session.multipartUpload(params, request); 
task.on("error", event => {
                console.dir(event);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(event))
                console.log(event.responseCode);
                console.log(event.response)
               // console.log((JSON.parse(event.response))
            });
```

result-

> eventName: "error" JS: object: { JS:   "_observers": { JS:
>   "complete": [ JS:       {} JS:     ], JS:     "error": [ JS:       {}
>   JS:     ], JS:     "responded": [ JS:       {} JS:     ] JS:   }, JS: 
>   "_session": { JS:     "_id": "file-upload" JS:   }, JS:   "_id":
>   "file-upload{1}", JS:   "_description": "Log File", JS:   "_upload":
>   4309, JS:   "_totalUpload": 4309, JS:   "_status": "error" JS: } JS:
>   error: "null" JS: responseCode: "400" JS: response:
>   net.gotev.uploadservice.ServerResponse@73e7f34

Expected : - response : { isSuccess:false, msg:'Token-Invalid' }

Answer (score 4):

The plugin do not parse the response on error event, but you could get the JSON response with following code on Android.

```
const responseObj = event.response && JSON.parse(event.response.getBodyAsString());
```